# cfoutput results by year and month using a group?

Tags: coldfusion

I want to output results from a query that has results like this ,query=gettotalstars
[image]

I using `<cfoutput query="GetTotalStars" group="month">`
but this repeats the output for all.
Is there another way to do this not using 'group' or maybe a better way to do it?

In the end i would like like it to show the output like this:(obviously from the way i have the table set up right now it wont give me the results the way i want it)

[image]

Here is the code im using right now:

```
<cfoutput query="GetTotalStars" group="month">   
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">  
  <thead><th></th><th>January</th><th>Frebruary</th>......</thead>  
  <tbody>  
  <cfloop query="GetTotalStars" >  
  <tr>  
  <td>#csedept_name#</td>  
  <td><div align="right">#TOTALSTARS#</div></td>  
  </tr>  
  </cfloop>  
  </tbody>  
  </cfoutput>  

  </table>
```

Comment: As @Michael suggested, it is preferable to aggregate in the database, if possible. 1) What is your DBMS? 2) Do these results ever span multiple years (2013,2014, ...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of controversy in the previous responses.  I will try to present the simplest solution based on what you have shown. There are a number of issues that you will have to address for yourself if you have multiple years or if you have null data for any given month.  While trying to lead you towards understanding without actually doing all the work, I have in fact given you an exact solution to this set of facts.  You will need to adjust and back off some of this to handle holes in your data, or other possible edge cases.  All in all, it should lead you to an approach that you can build on to handle these other possibilities.  It does use a query of query to tease out the header row.  I think that is the part that is leading to more complex solutions.

```
<cfscript>
    GetTotalStars = querynew(
        "dept_id,csedept_name,totalstars,year,month",
        "integer, varChar, integer, integer, integer",
        [
            {
            dept_id:1
            ,csedept_name:'department 1'
            ,totalstars:5
            ,year:2014
            ,month:5
            }
            ,{
            dept_id:1
            ,csedept_name:'department 1'
            ,totalstars:4
            ,year:2014
            ,month:6
            }
            ,{
            dept_id:2
            ,csedept_name:'department 2'
            ,totalstars:3
            ,year:2014
            ,month:5
            }
            ,{
            dept_id:2
            ,csedept_name:'department 2'
            ,totalstars:6
            ,year:2014
            ,month:6
            }
        ]
    );

writedump(GetTotalStars);
</cfscript>


<!---
    I agree with previous arguments about exessive use of query of queries.
    But for your header row (and to get a full list of possible months), you
    really need to pull that out of the original query in a single list or array or struct
--->

<cfquery dbtype="query" name="qryMonths">
    select distinct [month] from GetTotalStars order by [month]
</cfquery>


<cfoutput>

    <table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Department</th>

            <!---
                If you have gaps in the data, it might make sense to build an
                array here to keep track of what month is in what column
             --->
            <cfloop query="qryMonths">
                <th>#MonthAsString(qryMonths.month)#</th>
            </cfloop>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!---
                This is just a straightforward nested query and group loop.
                If you have nulls in the data, you would check against the array
                that you built in the top section to figure out which column you
                are in
             --->
            <cfloop query="GetTotalStars" group="csedept_name">
                <tr>
                    <td>#GetTotalStars.csedept_name#</td>
                    <cfloop group="month">
                        <td>#GetTotalStars.totalstars#</td>
                    </cfloop>
                </tr>
            </cfloop>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Some earlier versions of CF don't allow the group attribute with CFLOOP.  If using one, just switch to <cfoutput>

Comment: you are correct , well atleast my version does not allow this ,

Comment: @GerryGurevich Very nice Gerry +1 upvote for sleek and commented code!

Comment: This is ok for the question as it was asked.  However, it may be necessary to do something about reports spanning more than 1 calendar year.

Comment: @user3591637 This code will work in older versions if you get rid of the outermost <cfoutput> tags that don't have any attributes.  Then replace every cfloop with cfoutput and don't change the attributes.  Should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention your DBMS. However, if you are using SQL Server 2005+, consider using a [PIVOT](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx). An advantage of PIVOT is you can generate all of the month columns ie "January,February, ..." automatically. No need to handle missing months within your output loop. Plus, the aggregation takes place in the database, which means pulling less data/rows across into CF.

That said, all of the options for this type of report have pros and cons. A disadvantage of PIVOT is that it is a little more rigid and harder to customize.

Below is an quick example using a dummy table. It produces a resultset containing the department details, plus one column for each month:

```
 DEPT_ID | CSEDEPT_NAME | YEARNO | JANUARY | FEBRUARY | MARCH | ...
```

Simply run your cfquery. Then loop through it and output all of the query columns as usual.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f72fe/1)

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
        --- dummy table to simulate the current query
        SELECT dept_id
          , csedept_name
          , datePart(yyyy, ratingDate) AS YearNo
          , dateName(mm, ratingDate) AS MonthName
          , totalStars
        FROM  yourResults
      ) 
      AS r
      PIVOT
      (
        --- Using month names for clarity and demo purposes, but 
        --- you could just as easily use month numbers instead
        SUM(totalStars)
        FOR [MonthName] IN (
            [January],[February],[March],[April]
            , [May],[June],[July],[August], [September]
            , [October],[November],[December]
           )
      ) 
      AS pvt
```

Comment: wow , i have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.0.2531.0, sql server 2008, going to try to use it , never use pivot before going to look more into it

Comment: Thanks. `PIVOT` was a nice addition to SQL Server 2005. Before that you had to use the old `CASE` hack. It got the job done, but was .. tres ugly ;-)

Comment: @user3591637 - If you run into questions on how to plug your current query into the "--- dummy table to simulate ..." section, let me know.

Comment: @leigh do you know where i can look for a toturial on how i would be able to do it? i change the query to get the data i want

Comment: @user3591637 - The link in my answer explains how to use `PIVOT`. In theory, simply replace the `select` below the comment `--- dummy table ...` with your current JOIN. If you are having trouble with it, post your table structure and the current query to http://sqlfiddle.com so we can see it, and explain how to modify it.

Comment: @leight just got it to work the query, now to see how to ouput the results

Comment: If you used the example above, dump the cfquery. You will see it contains department, plus one column for each month name: "January", "February", ...  Just output the query columns as usual. ie `<cfoutput query="someQuery">#someQuery.dept_id# #someQuery.January# #someQuery.February#....</cfoutput>`

Answer (score -5):

This can help:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr><th>Dep</th><th>May</th><th>June</th></tr>
<cfoutput query="GetTotalStars" group="dept_id">
<tr><td>#csedept_name#</td><cfoutput><td>#totalstars#</td></cfoutput></tr>

</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Comment: Minus 1.  You have three column headers and two data columns.  Plus you have the month names hard coded and they might be query results.