# How to Output results based on year from query?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query:

```
<cfquery  name="pivotquery">
  SELECT employeedept,cse_name,YEAR,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December
  FROM (
        SELECT month= datename(month,execoffice_date) 
              , YEAR =YEAR(execoffice_date)
              ,  employeedept
              , COUNT(*) as 'totalstars'
        FROM CSEReduxResponses
        WHERE execoffice_status = 1
        GROUP BY  employeedept
               , month(execoffice_date)
               , YEAR(execoffice_date)
               , DATENAME(month,execoffice_date)
      ) 
      AS r 

      JOIN csedept d ON d.cse_dept = r.employeedept

  PIVOT
    (
        SUM(totalStars)
        FOR [month] IN  (
                [January],[February],[March],[April],
                [May],[June],[July],[August],
                [September],[October],[November],[December]
        )
    ) 
    AS pvt

</cfquery>
```

This gets me all the data I want based on the month and year.
I'm outputing the results in a table:

```
<table >
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>January</th>
    <th>Frebruary</th>
    .........
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <cfoutput query="pivotquery" >
    <tr>
        <td>#pivotquery.csedept_name#</td>
        <td>#pivotquery.January#</td>
        <td>#pivotquery.February#</td>
        ....... 
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Yes is outputting the data correctly. How can I get it to output the results in a separate table by year?

If you take a look at this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09fd8/1), it has 2014 and 2015 data. So I would like generate a separate table for each year. So with the data I created in the sqlfiddle, it would have 2 tables: one for 2014 and 2015.

Comment: I looked at the fiddle and saw nothing useful.  What is supposed to go into the yearly tables, the monthly totals for the year, or the annual total?

Comment: i think the sqlfiddle site is down or something , is that what you mean by saw nothing useful?

Comment: Their site must be down or having problems. Currently it is either producing an error or blank page for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how you want things to be displayed.  But since it looks like your data is ordered by year then you should be able to display by year via grouping your cfoutput by year.  So something like:

```
<cfoutput query="pivotquery" group="YEAR">
<table >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Department for #pivotquery.YEAR#</th>
    <th>January</th>
    <th>Frebruary</th>
    .........
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <cfoutput>
            <tr>
            <td>#pivotquery.csedept_name#</td>
            <td>#pivotquery.January#</td>
    <td>#pivotquery.February#</td>
    ....... 

            </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</table>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: actually the query is not order by year is just outputting it in the sqlfiddle like that but thanks

Comment: Then just be sure and either change the query to order by year or do a QoQ to re-sort the query results.  I only made note of it above because was not certain if your DB server was or would always return it ordered by year.

Comment: (Edit) @user3591637 - Yes, but you should not need a QoQ. Just add an "order by" to your sql query. Be sure to order by "year" first, then any other columns you want (Department name, etcetera). Otherwise, the "group" will not work properly. Also, I would recommend not using reserved words like "month" or "year" as column names. I used "MonthName" and "YearNo" in the [original example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075373/cfoutput-results-by-year-and-month-using-a-group/24086888#24086888).

Comment: @user3591637 - Sure it does. You probably have it in the wrong spot. Put the `ORDER BY` at the very end, after the `AS pvt` alias. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09fd8/5/0

Comment: I do not work much with SQL Server so never have used Pivot but if it does not work with an order by or takes "interesting methods" to make it work is why I mentioned the QoQ.  I do agree on using different column names since otherwise might find yourself needing to use quotes or brackets around the existing ones in some situations since reserved names.